# 'git clone' with msysGit on Windows not working

Tags: git, msysgit

I have installed msysGit on several of my computers and only have problems on one particular computer (my main work computer of course). 'git clone' does not work. When I run the clone command on a repository, this occurs:

```
C:\Projects>git clone git://github.com/[user]/[project].git
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Projects/[project]/.git/
```

It starts populating the .git directory, but never pulls down anything else. I've left it going for a couple of hours to see if it would at least throw an error. It continues to sit there. If I try and cancel it, it works just fine. It just never seems to pull the repository down. I've tried this on multiple repositories from multiple places. Does anyone have a clue what may be happening?

Comment: Are you able to access http://github.com/ with internet explorer (just incase you're using firefox as your primary browser). I believe msysgit uses wininet. if ie's connection settings are not configured (maybe you need a proxy?), wininet based apps don't work.

Comment: I'm able to browse github.com with IE and I'm even able to browse any of the public repositories.

Comment: Just completed my answer, suggesting to use msysgit1.6.0 for GitHub repo cloning.

Comment: Just completed again my answer: Git1.6.4.4 does contain a fix, but msysgit has yet to release a new build since 1.6.4 (which is understandable, they certainly want to include other evolutions as well)

Comment: You could also try Git 1.6.5 with msysGit as described on my blog ( http://asimilatorul.com/adapter/post/git-on-windows-with-msysgit/ ), I'm happily using github and other repositories over git, ssh, and http protocols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try to clone with the http address?

The is currently a ticket with msysgit ([issue 136](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=316)) with the same problem, for which the current workaround is to clone with the http rather than the git address.

Other moves to try:

- `GIT_TRACE=1` (and post the output)
- try with other or older versions of msysgit
- check for any firewall/antivirus issue on your main computer

---

Here switching to an older version of msysgit could be the right option:
See this [GitHub support thread](http://support.github.com/discussions/repos/957-cant-clone-over-http-or-git):

> > Are you using the 1.6.4 prerelease of msysGit? There are known bugs with it.
> > We recommend a stable version, such as 1.6.0.
>
> thanks chris, that's it: after switching back to the previous version of msysGit  (Git-1.6.3.2-preview20090608.exe) the problem does not occur any more.

---

The problem might actually affect any Git1.6.4 and older:

> git tries to check if the pack file exists by sending out a `HEAD` request, but chokes on the 500 error that some (if not all) github returns.
>
> Using the repository used by the reporter:

```
$ curl http://github.com/grails/grails.git/objects/info/packs
P pack-1290e84bed53bda28f0989dca48d836bd9104031.pack
P pack-bf40d38ae780512994e5127e832ed9d8853c186d.pack
P pack-f490d5f7d4671368f4a52c618ca9dce13b714ba1.pack
P pack-79e3a7f30e8989acc8403ac688be669a05384eef.pack

$ curl -I http://github.com/grails/grails.git/objects/pack/pack-bf40d38ae780512994e5127e832ed9d8853c186d.pack
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: nginx/0.6.26
Date: Fri, 04 Sep 2009 13:50:20 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 3193
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

See [this thread](http://marc.info/?l=git&m=125207099201971&w=2).
The GitHub support teams is currently investigating the problem:

> I don't think the 500s are intentional, but there may be something odd with our setup that is causing them.
> I have a ticket open to investigate the issue further. I have a feeling we won't be messing with this till after the move, since it's likely something with the server config.

---

Git1.6.4.4 does [contain a fix](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/RelNotes-1.6.4.4.txt) since September, 16th:

> The workaround for Github server that sometimes gave 500 (Internal server error) response to HEAD requests in 1.6.4.3 introduced a regression that caused re-fetching projects over http to `segfault` in certain cases due to uninitialized pointer being freed.

But [mssysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) has yet to release (September 21th) any new build since the original 1.6.4 late July. (They are probably waiting for 1.6.5 or 1.7)

Comment: I tried using http rather than git. It appeared to work but on every repository it gets to a point where it says `error: Unable to verify pack 'stuff' is available` several times and ends with `fatal: Fetch failed.`

I'm hooked straight up to the Internet with no firewall or antivirus in the middle for testing. Running `GIT_TRACE=1` didn't show anything. I'll try an older version tomorrow and see if that helps it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, man! I'm pretty detailed with searches and I looked all over for this and couldn't find anything. That was the exact problem I was having. I installed the 1.6.3 version (as mentioned by the person after Chris' suggestion of 1.6.0). It still doesn't work for the git protocol but works just fine with http.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem, and it turned out that it was the step accepting the remote host key that was blocking. I just ssh'd normally to the host, accepted the key, and then went back to git and everything was working.